# Crystal reports address label displays one one label in a row instead of two

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Using Crystal reports to print the address labels. Two labels are displayed per row.

The crystal format chosen is of type mailing list( 6 rows X 2 item per row)

An image is added in each of the mailing list label.

Sometimes for some strange reasons, the report displays only one address label per row. It happens some time only.

Is this a problem with the design of the reports OR with the length of the label row data?

I am using crystal reports comes with the Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you always using the same machine, same printer etc?

If i was too take a guess from the above i'd say it was the attached printer/paper size impacting the number of labels per row. Try disassociating the printer/paper with the report.

Comment: Thanks. Yes its the same machine. Even before its goes to the printer, the application shows the generated reports in Crystal Report Viewer. In the Viewer only that particular machine, its shows up only one column of address labels. However the same application build displaying 2 columns of address labels on another machine.